# Generically Flatten Json using c#

Tags: c#, json

I want to generically flatten some json so I can convert to a datatable and bind to a datagrid using c#

What is the best way of doign it, bearing in mind I dont know how many levels I am going down?

e.g.

```json
{
  "appointmentid": 4,
  "policyid": 1,
  "guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "number": "1234567890",
  "ampm": "false",
  "date": "2015-09-08T00:00:00",
  "vehicle": {
    "id": 1,
    "guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "make": null,
    "model": null
  },
  "installer": {
    "installerid": "1",
    "name": "Installer 1",
    "contact": "qwerty",
    "qascore": "0",
    "address1": "qwerty",
    "address2": "qwerty",
    "address3": null,
    "address4": null,
    "city": "qwertyu",
    "county": "qwertyu",
    "postcode": "asdfghj",
    "country": "GB",
    "email": "asdfghj",
    "web": "asdfghjk",
    "archived": false
  },
  "installations": [
    {
      "installationid": 6,
      "installationstatus": {
        "installationstatusid": 4,
        "installationstatus": "FAIL"
      },
      "isactive": true
    },
    {
      "installationid": 7,
      "installationstatus": {
        "installationstatusid": 1,
        "installationstatus": "NEW"
      },
      "isactive": false
    }
  ],
  "archived": false
}
```

I would like to extend this (I suppose I could iterate over the datatable on I had converted it) rather than installations.1.installationid, I would get installationid1.

as I'm going to be displaying the resulting datatable in a grid I would like to keep the column names friendly.

Comment: There is a hierarchy here. How do you expect it to be as a datatable ?

Comment: Yes but this is purely for viewing in a grid. The columns are selected based on a field in the db so the hierarchy doesn't matter in this case

Comment: Your question is not very well specified.  Let's say you had a generic way to transform the above JSON hierarchy to a data table.  What would be the columns and rows that you would see in your grid?

Comment: Hi Brian. Ideally I would like to retain unque values. But as I mentioned at the end it could be something like installations.1.installationid

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) to parse the data into a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) structure.  From there, you can use a recursive helper method to walk the structure and flatten it to a `Dictionary<string, object>` where the keys are the "path" to each value from the original JSON.  I would write it something like this:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> DeserializeAndFlatten(string json)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        JToken token = JToken.Parse(json);
        FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, token, "");
        return dict;
    }

    private static void FillDictionaryFromJToken(Dictionary<string, object> dict, JToken token, string prefix)
    {
        switch (token.Type)
        {
            case JTokenType.Object:
                foreach (JProperty prop in token.Children<JProperty>())
                {
                    FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, prop.Value, Join(prefix, prop.Name));
                }
                break;

            case JTokenType.Array:
                int index = 0;
                foreach (JToken value in token.Children())
                {
                    FillDictionaryFromJToken(dict, value, Join(prefix, index.ToString()));
                    index++;
                }
                break;

            default:
                dict.Add(prefix, ((JValue)token).Value);
                break;
        }
    }

    private static string Join(string prefix, string name)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? name : prefix + "." + name);
    }
}
```

Using this `DeserializeAndFlatten` method with your JSON you would end up with key-value pairs like this:

```
appointmentid: 4
policyid: 1
guid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
number: 1234567890
ampm: false
date: 9/8/2015 12:00:00 AM
vehicle.id: 1
vehicle.guid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
vehicle.make:
vehicle.model:
installer.installerid: 1
installer.name: Installer 1
installer.contact: qwerty
installer.qascore: 0
installer.address1: qwerty
installer.address2: qwerty
installer.address3:
installer.address4:
installer.city: qwertyu
installer.county: qwertyu
installer.postcode: asdfghj
installer.country: GB
installer.email: asdfghj
installer.web: asdfghjk
installer.archived: False
installations.0.installationid: 6
installations.0.installationstatus.installationstatusid: 4
installations.0.installationstatus.installationstatus: FAIL
installations.0.isactive: True
installations.1.installationid: 7
installations.1.installationstatus.installationstatusid: 1
installations.1.installationstatus.installationstatus: NEW
installations.1.isactive: False
archived: False
```

If you're looking to make the keys more human friendly, you could use a little string manipulation to cut them down.  Maybe something like this:

```
var dict = JsonHelper.DeserializeAndFlatten(json);
foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    int i = kvp.Key.LastIndexOf(".");
    string key = (i > -1 ? kvp.Key.Substring(i + 1) : kvp.Key);
    Match m = Regex.Match(kvp.Key, @"\.([0-9]+)\.");
    if (m.Success) key += m.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + kvp.Value);
}
```

That would give you this output instead:

```
appointmentid: 4
policyid: 1
guid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
number: 1234567890
ampm: false
date: 9/8/2015 12:00:00 AM
id: 1
guid: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
make:
model:
installerid: 1
name: Installer 1
contact: qwerty
qascore: 0
address1: qwerty
address2: qwerty
address3:
address4:
city: qwertyu
county: qwertyu
postcode: asdfghj
country: GB
email: asdfghj
web: asdfghjk
archived: False
installationid0: 6
installationstatusid0: 4
installationstatus0: FAIL
isactive0: True
installationid1: 7
installationstatusid1: 1
installationstatus1: NEW
isactive1: False
archived: False
```

But note, with this arrangement, you have lost some context: for example, you can see that there are now two identical `archived` keys, whereas in the original JSON they were distinct because they appeared in different parts of the hierarchy (`installer.archived` vs. `archived`).  You will need to figure out how to deal with that problem on your own.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gzhWHk

Comment: thank fo rthe code and the fiddle. One question however, if i pass in an array of appointments, then the resulting dictionary has 0.appointmentid etc. How would I be best stripping this out at the top level? after the dictionary is created, as per a regex example? or during the gerenic flatten method?

Comment: @brian, your approach is much more elegant than mm ine!

Comment: @MatthewFlynn I think you're better off manipulating the keys after the fact, because the recursive method as written requires that the keys be unique (by virtue of its using a dictionary to accumulate the values).  Not to say you couldn't do it during the recursion, but if you went that route you would need to change the logic to be able to handle duplicate keys.

Comment: Just amazing... thank you. what if it was a list of the same object? right now it will return 0.appointmentid=1  .... 1.appointmentid =2 ,.........
is there any way to save them in array or list?

Answer (score 26):

Using the library [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) You could use the JSONPath `$..*` to get all members of the JSON structure and filter out the ones with no children to skip the container properties.

e.g.

```
var schemaObject = JObject.Parse(schema);
var values = schemaObject
    .SelectTokens("$..*")
    .Where(t => !t.HasValues)
    .ToDictionary(t => t.Path, t => t.ToString());
```

Comment: This actually works, and is simpler and more elegant; kudos

Comment: Elegant solution, thank you

Answer (score 16):

Another variant using Newtonsoft's Json.NET [LINQ to JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) for object at root (the same can be done with `JArray` also):

```
var flattened = JObject.Parse(json)
    .Descendants()
    .OfType<JValue>()
    .ToDictionary(jv => jv.Path, jv => jv.ToString())
```

Comment: This is the clearest answer with the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Looked also for a solution and that did the job for me. Used new C# 7 Tupels for the result set. If anyone have another lightweight solution i'm interested:-)

```
async Task Main()
{
    var jsonUsers = await new HttpClient().GetStringAsync(@"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users");

    foreach (var flattedChild in GetFlatJsonChilds(JToken.Parse(jsonUsers)))
        Console.WriteLine($"{flattedChild.path}: {flattedChild.value}");
}

IEnumerable<(string path, string value)> GetFlatJsonChilds(JToken token)
{
    foreach (var child in token.Children())
    {   
        if(token.Type != JTokenType.Array &&token.Children().First().Type != JTokenType.Property && !child.Children().Any())
            yield return (child.Path, child.ToString());
        foreach(var childChild in GetFlatJsonChilds(child))
            yield return childChild;
    }
}
```

The Result for https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users :

```
[0].id: 1
[0].name: Leanne Graham
[0].username: Bret
[0].email: Sincere@april.biz
[0].address.street: Kulas Light
[0].address.suite: Apt. 556
[0].address.city: Gwenborough
[0].address.zipcode: 92998-3874
[0].address.geo.lat: -37.3159
[0].address.geo.lng: 81.1496
[0].phone: 1-770-736-8031 x56442
[0].website: hildegard.org
[0].company.name: Romaguera-Crona
[0].company.catchPhrase: Multi-layered client-server neural-net
[0].company.bs: harness real-time e-markets
[1].id: 2
[1].name: Ervin Howell
[1].username: Antonette
[1].email: Shanna@melissa.tv
[1].address.street: Victor Plains
[1].address.suite: Suite 879
[1].address.city: Wisokyburgh
[1].address.zipcode: 90566-7771
[1].address.geo.lat: -43.9509
[1].address.geo.lng: -34.4618
[1].phone: 010-692-6593 x09125
[1].website: anastasia.net
[1].company.name: Deckow-Crist
[1].company.catchPhrase: Proactive didactic contingency
[1].company.bs: synergize scalable supply-chains
[2].id: 3
[2].name: Clementine Bauch
[2].username: Samantha
[2].email: Nathan@yesenia.net
[2].address.street: Douglas Extension
[2].address.suite: Suite 847
[2].address.city: McKenziehaven
[2].address.zipcode: 59590-4157
[2].address.geo.lat: -68.6102
[2].address.geo.lng: -47.0653
[2].phone: 1-463-123-4447
[2].website: ramiro.info
[2].company.name: Romaguera-Jacobson
[2].company.catchPhrase: Face to face bifurcated interface
[2].company.bs: e-enable strategic applications
[3].id: 4
[3].name: Patricia Lebsack
[3].username: Karianne
[3].email: Julianne.OConner@kory.org
[3].address.street: Hoeger Mall
[3].address.suite: Apt. 692
[3].address.city: South Elvis
[3].address.zipcode: 53919-4257
[3].address.geo.lat: 29.4572
[3].address.geo.lng: -164.2990
[3].phone: 493-170-9623 x156
[3].website: kale.biz
[3].company.name: Robel-Corkery
[3].company.catchPhrase: Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity
[3].company.bs: transition cutting-edge web services
[4].id: 5
[4].name: Chelsey Dietrich
[4].username: Kamren
[4].email: Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca
[4].address.street: Skiles Walks
[4].address.suite: Suite 351
[4].address.city: Roscoeview
[4].address.zipcode: 33263
[4].address.geo.lat: -31.8129
[4].address.geo.lng: 62.5342
[4].phone: (254)954-1289
[4].website: demarco.info
[4].company.name: Keebler LLC
[4].company.catchPhrase: User-centric fault-tolerant solution
[4].company.bs: revolutionize end-to-end systems
[5].id: 6
[5].name: Mrs. Dennis Schulist
[5].username: Leopoldo_Corkery
[5].email: Karley_Dach@jasper.info
[5].address.street: Norberto Crossing
[5].address.suite: Apt. 950
[5].address.city: South Christy
[5].address.zipcode: 23505-1337
[5].address.geo.lat: -71.4197
[5].address.geo.lng: 71.7478
[5].phone: 1-477-935-8478 x6430
[5].website: ola.org
[5].company.name: Considine-Lockman
[5].company.catchPhrase: Synchronised bottom-line interface
[5].company.bs: e-enable innovative applications
[6].id: 7
[6].name: Kurtis Weissnat
[6].username: Elwyn.Skiles
[6].email: Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz
[6].address.street: Rex Trail
[6].address.suite: Suite 280
[6].address.city: Howemouth
[6].address.zipcode: 58804-1099
[6].address.geo.lat: 24.8918
[6].address.geo.lng: 21.8984
[6].phone: 210.067.6132
[6].website: elvis.io
[6].company.name: Johns Group
[6].company.catchPhrase: Configurable multimedia task-force
[6].company.bs: generate enterprise e-tailers
[7].id: 8
[7].name: Nicholas Runolfsdottir V
[7].username: Maxime_Nienow
[7].email: Sherwood@rosamond.me
[7].address.street: Ellsworth Summit
[7].address.suite: Suite 729
[7].address.city: Aliyaview
[7].address.zipcode: 45169
[7].address.geo.lat: -14.3990
[7].address.geo.lng: -120.7677
[7].phone: 586.493.6943 x140
[7].website: jacynthe.com
[7].company.name: Abernathy Group
[7].company.catchPhrase: Implemented secondary concept
[7].company.bs: e-enable extensible e-tailers
[8].id: 9
[8].name: Glenna Reichert
[8].username: Delphine
[8].email: Chaim_McDermott@dana.io
[8].address.street: Dayna Park
[8].address.suite: Suite 449
[8].address.city: Bartholomebury
[8].address.zipcode: 76495-3109
[8].address.geo.lat: 24.6463
[8].address.geo.lng: -168.8889
[8].phone: (775)976-6794 x41206
[8].website: conrad.com
[8].company.name: Yost and Sons
[8].company.catchPhrase: Switchable contextually-based project
[8].company.bs: aggregate real-time technologies
[9].id: 10
[9].name: Clementina DuBuque
[9].username: Moriah.Stanton
[9].email: Rey.Padberg@karina.biz
[9].address.street: Kattie Turnpike
[9].address.suite: Suite 198
[9].address.city: Lebsackbury
[9].address.zipcode: 31428-2261
[9].address.geo.lat: -38.2386
[9].address.geo.lng: 57.2232
[9].phone: 024-648-3804
[9].website: ambrose.net
[9].company.name: Hoeger LLC
[9].company.catchPhrase: Centralized empowering task-force
[9].company.bs: target end-to-end models
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one another way to flatten JSON / convert to DataTable using [Cinchoo ETL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ChoETL.JSON/)

**Flatten JSON:**

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("*** JSON file path ***"))
{
    foreach (var rec in r.Select(f => f.Flatten()))
        Console.WriteLine(rec.Dump());
}
```

**JSON to DataTable:**

```
using (var r = new ChoJSONReader("*** JSON file path ***"))
{
    var dt = r.AsDataTable();
    Console.WriteLine(dt.DumpAsJson());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Deserialize, then LINQ select to flatten. I'm guessing, since you haven't stated it, that you want all the appointment and installer information on the same record as the specific installation?

My initial idea would be to leverage dynamics so that you can avoid having to put in static schemas for your JSON. If you already have static types that can act as JSON schemas, then you can avoid dynamics (and all that it entails).  Here's an example class - using JSON.NET - to illustrate what I'm thinking:

```
public class DeserializeAndFlatten
{
    public dynamic ParseJson()
    {
        var appointment = JObject.Parse(JsonData.JSON_TO_PARSE);  // <-- replace the constant w/ the real JSON...

        // this is where you flatten it all out!
        // not going to put all the fields in, that would kill the example, LOL
        var installations = appointment["installations"].Select(installation => new
        {
            appointmentId = appointment["appointmentid"],
            policyId = appointment["policyid"],

            vehicleId = appointment["vehicle"]["id"],
            vehicleMake = appointment["vehicle"]["make"],
            vehicleModel = appointment["vehicle"]["model"],

            installerId = appointment["installer"]["installerid"],
            installerName = appointment["installer"]["name"],

            installationId = installation["installationid"],
            installationStatus = installation["installationstatus"]["installationstatus"],
            installationStatusId = installation["installationstatus"]["installationstatusid"],
        }).ToList();

        return installations;
    }
}
```

You can test the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jsonParser = new DeserializeAndFlatten();
        var installations = jsonParser.ParseJson();

        // FYI we get back a dynamic listing, 
        // so intellisense wont work...
        foreach (var installation in installations)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"appointmentId: {installation.appointmentId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"installer: {installation.installerName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"installation id: {installation.installationId}");
            Console.WriteLine($"status: {installation.installationStatus}");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to have a generic solution. So is it not possible to generically flatten it? I.e with no concept of the fields being returned or the depth. As the view is gong to be used across my api so there any data could be returned.

Comment: It's definitely possible. Instead of specifying the fields by name, you would have to iterate all the fields. The complexity would be in having to initially traverse the JSON data hierarchy and identify the depth and sibling data at various depths. There's so many clever ways to do this, I've had to do that sort of work before, except that my generic output was from the JSON into an excel spreadsheet. The sample I've shown should be a decent starting point to start exploring different possibilities. The world is your oyster!

Comment: I was thinking of possibly using something recursive. So does jobject.parse return the items in a nested array structure?

Comment: Yes, it does. It basically will look like a domain object representing the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

For those who need same in F#:

```
module JsonFlatten =

let Join prefix name =
    if String.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) then name else prefix + "." + name

let rec FillDictionaryFromJToken (dict:Dictionary<string, string>) (token:JToken) (prefix:string) =
    match token.Type with
    | JTokenType.Object ->
        for prop in token.Children<JProperty>() do
            FillDictionaryFromJToken dict prop.Value (Join prefix prop.Name)
    | JTokenType.Array ->
        let mutable index = 0

        for value in token.Children() do
            FillDictionaryFromJToken dict  value (Join prefix (index.ToString()))
            index <- index + 1
    | _ ->
        dict.Add(prefix, sprintf "%A" (token :?> JValue).Value)

let DeserializeAndFlatten(json:string) =
    let dict = Dictionary<string, string>()
    let token = JToken.Parse(json);
    FillDictionaryFromJToken dict  token ""
    dict
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to load some JSON into a key/value list today, and decided to use the Microsoft configuration in .NET from "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration":

```
ConfigurationBuilder jsonConfigurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
jsonConfigurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(fileName, false, false);
IConfiguration jsonConfiguration = jsonConfigurationBuilder.Build();
```

Now the JSON is loaded and parset into IConfiguration, and then it is simple to get it into a list of key/value pairs using this method:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String, Object>> GetConfigurationEnumerator(IConfiguration configuration) {
    // Get the configuration child sections into a stack.
    Stack<IConfigurationSection> configurationSectionStack = new Stack<IConfigurationSection>();
    foreach (IConfigurationSection configurationSection in configuration.GetChildren()) {
        configurationSectionStack.Push(configurationSection);
    }

    // Return a key/value pair for each configuration section, and add additional child sections to the stack.
    while (configurationSectionStack.Count > 0) {
        // Get the configuration section.
        IConfigurationSection configurationSection = configurationSectionStack.Pop();

        // eturn a key/value pair.
        yield return new KeyValuePair<String, Object>(configurationSection.Path, configurationSection.Value);

        // Add the child sections to the stack.
        foreach (IConfigurationSection configurationSectionChild in configurationSection.GetChildren()) {
            configurationSectionStack.Push(configurationSectionChild);
        }
    }
} // GetConfigurationEnumerator
```

And write the result to the console:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<String, Object> value in GetConfigurationEnumerator(jsonConfiguration)) {
    Console.WriteLine($"  {value.Key}  ==  {value.Value}");
}
```

The result is like: "level0:level1:level2  ==  this is the value"

Answer (score 0):

Here is Brian Rogers answer updated for `JsonSerializer`:

```
public class JsonHelper
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> DeserializeAndFlatten(string json)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        var token = JsonObject.Parse(json);
        FillDictionaryFromNode(dict, token, "");
        return dict;
    }

    private static void FillDictionaryFromNode(Dictionary<string, object> dict, JsonNode token, string prefix)
    {
        if (token is JsonObject jobj)
        {
            foreach (var item in token.AsObject())
            {
                FillDictionaryFromNode(dict, item.Value, Join(prefix, item.Key));
            }
        }
        else if (token is JsonArray jarr)
        {
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var value in jarr)
            {
                FillDictionaryFromNode(dict, value, Join(prefix, index.ToString()));
                index++;
            }
        }
        else if (token is JsonValue jval)
        {
            dict.Add(prefix, jval.GetValue<string>());
        }
    }

    private static string Join(string prefix, string name)
    {
        return (string.IsNullOrEmpty(prefix) ? name : prefix + "." + name);
    }
}
```