# Serialise class to Dictionary<string, string>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have the following code preparing a dictionary before inserting into MemoryConfigurationSource

```
 var clientConfigurations = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<ClientConfigurations>("api/ClientConfiguration");

 var clientConfigurationsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>()
 {
      { "AzureAd:Authority", clientConfigurations.AzureAd.Authority },
      { "AzureAd:ClientId", clientConfigurations.AzureAd.ClientId },
      { "AzureAd:ValidateAuthority", $"{clientConfigurations.AzureAd.ValidateAuthority}" },
      { "AccessTokenScope", clientConfigurations.AccessTokenScope }

     };

 var memoryConfig = new MemoryConfigurationSource { InitialData = clientConfigurationsDictionary };
```

I want to make the second line a generic method that takes a class and returns a dictionary. Hoping to not reinvent to wheel by doing this myself via reflection. I'm looking for a library utility that already does this.

Note: the compound value of ClientConfigurations.AzureAd.Authority is broken down to "AzureAd:Authority".

Comment: What does "make this method more generic" mean to you?

Comment: Thanks for feedback I try reword that part

Comment: What does "takes a class and returns a dictionary" mean to you?

Comment: why not convert to dictionary in first line: 
`GetFromJsonAsync<Dictionary<string,string>>`

Comment: This question is too broad. you cant magic stuff into a dictionary in the way you have shown, without a bunch of rules and knowing the structure and at least some constraints on what the data is that needs to be processed.

Comment: Here's a solution deserializing json into a similar structure: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782937/5803406. You'd need to serialize your class back to json first, or just use the original json from the first line

Comment: The class represents a configuration read from the servers configuration. configuration.Get<LocalConfigurations>(). Which has a property of type ClientConfigurations

Comment: @devNull Perfect thankyou!