# How to convert json with subarray to data table

Tags: c#, json, datatable, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have converted a JSON to datatable. But don't know how to display it sub array part.

json is :

```
 {
"School": "xxxx",
"Location": "yyyyy",
"TotalStaffs": "50",
"StudentsCount": [
 {
  "ClassA": "80",
  "ClassB": "60"
}
]
}

 DataTable dt2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>("[" + json + "]");
```

Now the output is :

```
School  Location  TotalStaffs  StudentsCount
 xxxx    yyyy        50
```

The output should be :

```
School  Location  TotalStaffs   ClassA   ClassB
 xxxx    yyyy        50           80      60
```

NB : StudentsCount array is dynamic. There may be only one class sometime. Or may be more than one class. And the resulted table will always contain only one row, as shown in the sample.

Comment: There's probably a way to use something like newtonsofts `JObject.Parse(schema).SelectTokens("$..*")` to transform the input. Maybe based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57900473/4139809 ?

Answer (score 1):

Real output is correct. Your output breaks [normal forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). But if you need your output view anyway, you must make it by yourself. The easiest example:

```
DataTable dt2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject();
string output = $"{dt2}\t{string.Join("\t", dt2.StudentsCount)}";
```