# Find all Id's in json object

Tags: c#, json, string, object

I have a long tree json document, here is the part of it

```
"childs": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "name": "name1",
      "childs": []
    },
    {
      "id": "id2",
      "name": "name21",
      "childs": [
        {
          "id": "id3",
          "name": "name123124",
          "childs": [
            {
              "id": "id4",
              "name": "namewe1231",
              "childs": [
                {
                  "id": "id5",
                  "name": "name123123",
                  "childs": [
                    {
                      "id": "id5",
```

`

i need to save all id from this document for local storage like:
id1
id2
id3
id4 etc...
is it even possible? JObject and dynamic variable didnt help me.

heres code i've been trying to compile but it returned me just first id from tree
`

```
string source = File.ReadAllText(jsonModelPath);
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(source);
            File.WriteAllText(path, data.id);
```

`

Comment: I think one of the ideas is to flatten your object, and then select the properties with ids in it. See this post for some inspiration, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782937/generically-flatten-json-using-c-sharp

Comment: @CharlesHan yes, this post helped me to solve my problem, thank you very much

Comment: @AlexeySavelyev please post the final sample and close the post with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
string[] ids = JObject.Parse(json)
        .Descendants()
        .OfType<JProperty>()
        .Where(a => a.Name == "id")
        .Select(a => a.Value.ToString())
        .ToArray();
```

or you can put all ids in one line

```
 string strIds = string.Join(" ",ids);
```

or each id in the new line

```
 string strIds = string.Join("\n",ids);
```

and save

```
File.WriteAllText(path, strIds);
```