# How to generate query string with flattened param name from a nested object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I want to convert my below nested request to Query String

```cs
var parameter = new RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest()
{
    Chain = Chain.INPUT,
    Data = new RuleInputModel()
    {
        Protocol = "tcp",
        SourceIp = "2.2.2.2",
        DestinationIp = "1.1.1.1",
        SourcePort = "111",
        DestinationPort = "222",
        Jump = "DROP"
    }
};
```

to something like below

> Chain=INPUT&Data.DestinationIp=1.1.1.1&Data.DestinationPort=222&Data.Jump=DROP&Data.Protocol=tcp&Data.SourceIp=2.2.2.2&Data.SourcePort=111

WebSerializer workaround:

I try with the *WebSerializer* library with call `WebSerializer.ToQueryString(parameter)`. I see the below output:

> Chain=INPUT&Data=DestinationIp=1.1.1.1&DestinationPort=222&Jump=DROP&Protocol=tcp&SourceIp=2.2.2.2&SourcePort=111"

As you can see, the output is not as expected and my ASP.NET Web API .NET6 sample server does not accept this. (for more info you can see https://github.com/BSVN/IpTables.Api/pull/18)

Did you know another library for doing this or some trick to correct using *WebSerializer*?

Comment: _"As you can see, the output is incorrect."_ - Not exactly. It's flattened. So, it's not what you _expected_ but it's not particularly "incorrect". If it cannot be configured to not flatten, this may still be made to work overall.

Comment: Thanks, I change my word in question, Did you know to how to `WebSerializer` work in not flatten mode?

Comment: Just do a simple Replace and move on. 
 Looking for a tool to do something that is easy to fix, seems like a waste of time to me: `WebSerializer.ToQueryString(parameter).Replace("&", "&Data.").Replace("&Data.Data=", "&Data.")`

Comment: [Nested Type and Nameprefix](https://github.com/Cysharp/WebSerializer#nested-type-and-nameprefix) seems like what you want.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Did you can post answer for my question?

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods If I understand correctly, `WebSerializer` does not support this feature, Did you know better libarry for this?

Comment: _"WebSerializer does not support this feature"_ - it does. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
static List<(string Key, string Value)> SerializeObject(object obj, string parent) 
{
    var result = new List<(string Key, string Value)>();
    foreach (var p in obj.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead))
    {
        var v = p.GetValue(obj);
        if (v is null) continue;
        var pp = $"{(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parent) ? $"{parent}." : "")}{p.Name}";
    
        if (CanSeriazlieToString(p)) result.Add(new (pp, v!.ToString()!));
        else result.AddRange(SerializeObject(v, $"{pp}"));
    }
    return result;
}
static bool CanSeriazlieToString(PropertyInfo pInfo)
{
    return (pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(string) || pInfo.PropertyType == typeof(Guid) || pInfo.PropertyType.IsPrimitive);
}
var queryString = string.Join("&", SerializeObject(parameter, string.Empty).Select(x => $"{x.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.Value)}"));
```

Comment: Would say this approach is quite interesting and get my attention. Just a minor bug is that the `Chain` query param is not printed. Adding 1 more condition `pInfo.PropertyType.IsEnum`in `CanSeriazlieToString` method will solve the issue. =)

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you look for the answer other than using the `WebSerializer` way,

*Implement the `DataContract` attribute seems the quickest, but I highly doubt next time if you want to convert the `RuleInputModel` instance only to query string or if you have other models with the property with `RuleInputModel` type (but different name), it will result in the query param name will have the "Data." prefix.*

Thus, recommend writing a custom implementation for it. For this case, the expected result is flattened JSON and then converted to a query string.

You can use the *Newtonsoft.Json* library to achieve the JSON flattening, converting an object to `Dictionary<string, object>` type, credit to the [GuruStron's answer on Generically Flatten Json using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63487391/8017690).

For the second method will be converting the `Dictionary<string, object>` to query string.

```cs
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public static class Helpers
{
    public static Dictionary<string, object> FlattenObject<T>(T source)
        where T : class, new()
        {
            return JObject.FromObject(source)
                .Descendants()
                .OfType<JValue>()
                .ToDictionary(jv => jv.Path, jv => jv.Value<object>());
        }
    
    public static string ToQueryString(this Dictionary<string, object> dict)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        
        foreach (var kvp in dict)
        {
            sb.Append("&")
                .Append($"{kvp.Key}={HttpUtility.UrlEncode(kvp.Value.ToString())}");
        }
        
        return sb.ToString()
            .Trim('&');
    }
}
```

The minor change in your `RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest` class which you want to serialize the `Chain` value as string instead of integer.

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

public class RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Chain Chain { get; set; }
    
    public RuleInputModel Data { get; set; }
}
```

Caller method:

```cs
Helpers.FlattenObject(parameter)
        .ToQueryString();
```

Comment: [Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/X6Tn8w)

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work using [`WebSerializerAttribute`](https://github.com/Cysharp/WebSerializer#webserializerattribute):

```
using System;
using Cysharp.Web;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var parameter = new RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest()
            {
                Chain = Chain.INPUT,
                Data = new RuleInputModel()
                {
                    Protocol = "tcp",
                    SourceIp = "2.2.2.2",
                    DestinationIp = "1.1.1.1",
                    SourcePort = "111",
                    DestinationPort = "222",
                    Jump = "DROP"
                }
            };
        
        WebSerializer.ToQueryString(parameter).Dump();
    }
}

public enum Chain
{
    INPUT
}

public class RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest
{
    public Chain Chain {get; set;}

    [WebSerializer(typeof(RuleInputModelSerializer))]
    public RuleInputModel Data {get; set;}
}

public class RuleInputModel
{
    public string Protocol {get; set;}
    public string SourceIp {get; set;}
    public string DestinationIp {get; set;}
    public string SourcePort {get; set;}
    public string DestinationPort {get; set;}
    public string Jump {get; set;}
}

public class RuleInputModelSerializer : IWebSerializer<RuleInputModel>
{
    public void Serialize(ref WebSerializerWriter writer, RuleInputModel value, WebSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var prefix = writer.NamePrefix;
        writer.NamePrefix = "Data.";
        WebSerializer.ToQueryString(writer, value, options);
        writer.NamePrefix = prefix;
    }
}
```

Fiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/h28gKx

Output:

> Chain=INPUT&Data=Data.DestinationIp=1.1.1.1&Data.DestinationPort=222&Data.Jump=DROP&Data.Protocol=tcp&Data.SourceIp=2.2.2.2&Data.SourcePort=111

Answer (score 0):

If you want the query string parameters to include the "Data" prefix for the nested object properties, then try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var parameter = new RulesCommandServiceAppendRequest()
        {
            Chain = Chain.INPUT,
            Data = new RuleInputModel()
            {
                Protocol = "tcp",
                SourceIp = "2.2.2.2",
                DestinationIp = "1.1.1.1",
                SourcePort = "111",
                DestinationPort = "222",
                Jump = "DROP"
            }
        };

        string queryString = ConvertToQueryString("Data", parameter);
        Console.WriteLine(queryString);
    }

    static string ConvertToQueryString(string prefix, object obj)
    {
        var properties = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
        var queryStringParams = new List<string>();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj);
            if (value != null)
            {
                var propertyName = $"{prefix}.{property.Name}";
                if (property.PropertyType.IsClass && property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
                {
                    queryStringParams.Add(ConvertToQueryString(propertyName, value));
                }
                else
                {
                    queryStringParams.Add($"{propertyName}={Uri.EscapeDataString(value.ToString())}");
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Join("&", queryStringParams);
    }
}
```