How to parse nested json without knowing the structure
I have done it this far, this works for non nested. But how do I do for nested JSON.
I am not able to dynamically get all the values from the json,even for nested ones.


using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string json = @"
        [ 
            {""name"":{""first"":""NJ""} ,""age"":45}
        ]";
        
        JArray a = JArray.Parse(json);
        
        foreach (JObject o in a.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty p in o.Properties())
            
            {
                string name = p.Name;
                string value = (string)p.Value;
                Console.WriteLine(name + " -- " + value);
            }
        }
    }
}




How do you want "all the values from the json" to be stored? What C# type do you want it to be? In other words, how do you intend to get a particular value from "all the values"? Or do you just want to print them out and throw them away, like in the code you have shown here?

https://stackoverflow.com/q/4535840/5133585 might be relevant.

@Sweeper lets say store it in nested array and print as well

Can you [edit] your question to show an example JSON and show the "nested array" that you expect to get from the JSON?

they way, you wrote example it will throw exception in string value = (string)p.Value; line. try  JToken value = p.Value;

check this thread, (flatten json and go over each flattened property.) [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32782937/generically-flatten-json-using-c-sharp]
